# Remove words found in the second file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I need to compare 2 files and remove the words from the text file those are found in the second (exclude list) file.

```
# cat remove.txt
test
junk
trash
unwanted
bad
worse

# cat corpus.txt
this is a test message to check if bad words are removed correctly. The second line may or may not have unwanted words. The third line also need not be as clean as first and second line.
There can be paragraphs in the text corpus and the entire file should be checked for trash.
```

This python code is working as expected.

```
import re

stop_words = list()
with open("remove.txt", "r") as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        stop_words.append(i.replace("\n", ""))
        
# !> filteredtext.txt

file1 = open("corpus.txt")

line = file1.read()
words = line.split()

for r in words:
    r = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", "", r)
    if not r in stop_words:
        appendFile = open("filteredtext.txt", "a")
        appendFile.write(" " + r)
        appendFile.close()
```

I will like to know if there is linux command line magic possible in this case. The regular expression mentioned in the python code is optional. The cleaned text need not be 100% clean. More than 90% accuracy is ok.

Expected output:

```
 this is a message to check if words are removed correctly The second line may or may not have words The third line also need not be as clean as first and second line There can be paragraphs in the text corpus and the entire file should be checked for
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `gnu awk` command:

```sh
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'FNR == NR {seen[$1]; next} !($1 in seen) {ORS=RT; print}' remove.txt corpus.txt
```

On a 450MB `remove.txt` file above `awk` command took `1 min 16 sec` to complete.

To make it more readable:

```sh
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'FNR == NR {
   seen[$1]
   next
}
!($1 in seen) {
   ORS = RT
   print
}' remove.txt corpus.txt
```

---

**Earlier Solution:** Using a single `gnu sed` script:

```sh
sed -f <(sed 's~.*~s/ *\\<&\\> *//~' remove.txt) corpus.txt

this is amessage to check ifwords are removed correctly. The second line may or may not havewords. The third line also need not be as clean as first and second line.
There can be paragraphs in the text corpus and the entire file should be checked for.
```

Comment: my remove.txt file is very large (400 MB). This command did not complete with error message "killed".

Comment: In that case try 2 steps: `sed 's~.*~s/ *\\<&\\> *//~' remove.txt > remove.sed; sed -f remove.sed corpus.txt`

Comment: Still getting "killed" message.

Comment: btw you should mention this 400MB requirement in your question as well

Comment: Yes. I get error while running sed -f remove.sed corpus.txt

Comment: ok check my updated `gnu awk` solution. I tested it on `450MB remove.txt` file that took `1m 16sec` to finish.

Comment: This solution did not work.  My file has some non-english text. May be that must be a problem in this case. But it worked with Ravinder Singh's answer.

Comment: Wow non Ebgliah text. Just to tell you that I always post a tested solution. But you are bringing new facts through comments that are not part of posted problem.

Comment: Some unicode characters are getting merged. I tried both the commands. Yes, I should have mentioned the file size and type in the question.

Comment: ok try: `awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'FNR == NR {seen[$1]; next} !($1 in seen) {ORS=RT; print}' remove.txt corpus.txt`

Comment: This is correct. Please post it as answer. It is much readable than Ravinder Singh's answer. No need of detailed explanation. :) A comment on how it works will be helpful.

Comment: ok answer updated. It was my original awk solution but seeing a dot after `trash` changed my mind to other possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Will add detailed explanation in sometime too.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(count=="" && !($i in arr)){ count++ }
    printf("%s%s",!($i in arr)?$i:"",(i==NF?"":(!($i in arr)?OFS:"")))
  }
  if(count){printf ORS;count=""}
}' remove.txt cor.txt
```

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment to get only words which are matching from another file try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(count=="" && ($i in arr)){ count++ }
    printf("%s%s",($i in arr)?$i:"",(i==NF?"":(($i in arr)?OFS:"")))
  }
  if(count){printf ORS;count=""}
}' remove.txt cor.txt
```

Comment: How do I inverse the selection? In python, I can simply use "if r in stop_words:" instead of "not in" to get the string 'test bad unwanted trash'

Comment: @shantanuo, yes I am using same concept here, creating an array from remove.txt and then checking from another file field by field and keeping only those which are not present in array.

Comment: I am asking how to inverse the selection and keep only those which ARE present in array. I forgot to ask this question. So asking in this comment. - I want to print the stop words in the order as they appear in the text corpus.

Comment: @shantanuo, oh ok sure, I have added EDIT solution now for same, kindly do let me know if this helps you, cheers.

Comment: This is "very" fast compared to python. I appreciate your help. But it is adding a lot of blank lines and spaces. Should I use another command or you can do it in this script?

Comment: @shantanuo, ok sure please check my edited code now, this will not print empty lines, let me know how it goes and I hope we are Good now :)

Comment: Enter marks are still there! Empty lines are removed. Is it possible to print everything on a single line? A single long line for NLP training.

Comment: @shantanuo, when I checked your samples these codes worked fine for me, if you already have blank lines then we need to take care it with additional a bit code. Do you have blank lines already present in your file?

Comment: @shantanuo, I have edited the answers now to get everything into a single line, kindly check it once. Also if you want to have my previous answers too, please do let me know I can add them too in my answer, cheers

Comment: Your new command returns less number of words because some words are getting together,, for e.g. andthis. Your earlier command was correct as "and this". Please post that script as an answer. By putting everything on one line was like trying to make it readable. It was not a requirement as such.

Comment: @shantanuo, ok sure, done now, kindly double check it once and let me know if All is Well here :)

Comment: Yes. This is correct. The word count match with python script. The only difference is that python script completed after several hours while awk was instant :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
for r in words:
    r = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", "", r)
    if not r in stop_words:
        appendFile = open("filteredtext.txt", "a")
        appendFile.write(" " + r)
        appendFile.close()
```

but by doing that you are `open`-ing for every word which is not in `stop_words`, which takes time, it is more efficient to `open` once, do what you want and then `close` i.e.

```
appendFile = open("filteredtext.txt", "w")
for r in words:
    r = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", "", r)
    if r not in stop_words:
        appendFile.write(" " + r)
appendFile.close()
```

Note that I also used `w`rite mode as we do not need to `a`ppend in this case.

Comment: Tried. Takes a lot of time. Performance is no where near awk.

Comment: @shantanuo ok, then this means this is not bottleneck of this python code. For future use I suggest reading about *profiling* python code, as you might encounter cases when optimizing piece of existing python code might be easier than reworking whole code to another language.